# Unexplained extra rows after MySQL join

Tags: mysql, sql

I've stripped this down as much as possible, so I hope it's easy to understand. Currently, I have two tables with website data, `display` and `traffic`. Both tables have the columns `date` and `site`.

`display` has `revenue`,
`traffic` has `pageviews`.

My end goal is to produce results with revenue and pageviews for each of our sites, grouped by week. So, four columns: `week`, `site`, `pageviews`, `revenue` - where `week` is `week(date) AS week`.

Here is my best attempt so far:

```
SELECT display.site,
       Week(display.date) AS dateweek,
       Sum(revenue)       AS revenue,
       tr.pageviews
FROM   display
       INNER JOIN (SELECT traffic.site,
                          Week(date)     AS date_granularity,
                          Sum(pageviews) AS pageviews
                   FROM   traffic
                   GROUP  BY traffic.site,
                             date_granularity) AS tr
               ON tr.date_granularity = Week(display.date)
WHERE  display.site = 'Google'
GROUP  BY dateweek,
          display.site,
          tr.pageviews
```

*(Google is in place of the actual site name of our client)*

I will take week 17 from the results grid as an example:

```
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
|  site  | dateweek |      revenue       | pageviews |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
| Google |       17 | 1424.0631110000002 |   1151716 |
| Google |       17 | 1424.0631110000002 |   1169364 |
| Google |       17 | 1424.0631110000002 |   1427273 |
| Google |       17 | 1424.0631110000002 |   6776535 |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

Doing queries from the individual tables with no joins, this is the correct and expected output for week 17:

```
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
|  site  | dateweek |      revenue       | pageviews |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
| Google |       17 | 1424.0631110000002 |   1169364 |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-----------+
```

It feels like I'm so close, as the row I expect I'm already getting, but there's some random extras. Any ideas? If there's anything that's unclear I'm happy to add more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only put one `ON` condition, the `JOIN` will match the condition only. In your case, you're matching just the `WEEK` so that means regardless of any site from the subquery, as long as the `WEEK` value match, it will return result. The fix is very simple, you just need to add 1 more condition in `ON`, so:

```
SELECT display.site,
       Week(display.date) AS dateweek,
       Sum(revenue)       AS revenue,
       tr.pageviews
FROM   display
       INNER JOIN (SELECT traffic.site,
                          Week(date)     AS date_granularity,
                          Sum(pageviews) AS pageviews
                   FROM   traffic
                   GROUP  BY traffic.site,
                             date_granularity) AS tr
               ON tr.date_granularity = Week(display.date)
              /*add another condition here*/ 
               AND tr.site=display.site
WHERE  display.site = 'Google'
GROUP  BY dateweek,
          display.site,
          tr.pageviews
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bbbda2dd1cbdcc0698724c0557556d3d)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I didn't even know you could join on multiple conditions. Thank you.

Comment: It's basically can function the same as `WHERE`.. on `JOIN/INNER JOIN` it might not be different at all but on `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`, using condition in `ON` instead of in `WHERE` can show you more than one to one condition matching. I'm sure you'll get more understanding about it when you've have more practice  ;-)